# Ubuntu 22.10 Freezes computer

Tags: freeze

**Using Mate desktop** Computer is a 6 core AMD tower home computer. Just a couple years old. Daily usage.

Started to 'freeze' maybe once twice per week after upgrading from 22.04 LTS to 22.10 in late December. Those freezes were of short duration. I have the mouse roaming around the frozen page but but can't do or click on anything. Today though, was the 2nd time it froze so solidly, I had to do a hard reset.

The keyboard is inactive and none of the old tricks to recover from a frozen computer work, ALT+Pntsrn+reisub, ALT+SYSQ+F, CTRL+ALT+F1. None of them do anything at all. In fact, the RESET button on the computer doesn't work either, I have to flip off the power switch (hard reset).

Generally when it freezes, it comes back on it's own a few seconds later but this last time it's been so locked that after 15 minutes I flipped off the power switch as reset wouldn't work. Like I said, usually it soft locks for a few seconds 2 or 3 times a week, but now it's hard locked requiring a hard reset 2X.

It reminds me of a Windoze type of video hang. But there I could use CTRL+ALT+DEL.

What 'Log' should I post and where do I find it? I did find this hardware log, but not sure if it's the right thing. After all, I did have to do a hard reset.

I have it as a notepad file...but C&P doesn't work. How do I attach it?

Thanks.

Comment: It freezes at fix points a day somehow for me.

Ubuntu is approaching the bugginess of a Windows computer sadly. I hopped over to Ubuntu hoping to get away from the Windows woes but sadly this is not the case anymore

Comment: The occasional 'long pause' by Ubuntu 22.10 using Mate desktop did seem to fix itself in my case. After a couple of updates the problem went away. And then I tried to upgrade to 23.04 and that trashed my HDD, acted as though it was installing fine until reboot...wasn't able to recover from the BSOD so dropped back to my 2 month old full clone. After that was up an running, haven't noted any 'long pause' issues.